# In AS3, does removing a child from stage remove all references to it so that it can be cleaned up by the garbage collector?

Tags: actionscript-3, null, garbage-collection, removechild

I'm creating an AIR app that has a main class that creates lots of instances of a movieclip and adds them to a container. Throughout the use of the app, these clips are frequently destroyed and new ones created.

When I create these movieclips, my main class adds event listeners to them. The movieclips also have event listeners within themselves.

I use the following function to remove all of these movieclips from their container whenever I'm updating the display:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < this.mainContainer.numChildren; i++) 
        {
            mainContainer.removeChild(mainContainer.getChildAt(i));
            //mainContainer.getChildAt(i)=null;
        }
```

I'm wondering if this is sufficient to prepare those instances for garbage collection ie does that kill the event listeners added by my main class? Or do I need to go through and remove the event listeners first before removing each child?

Also, where does nulling each instance fit into this? The above commented out line gives the error:

```
1105: Target of assignment must be a reference value.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Remove ALL Children**

Your script won't remove all children of **mainContainer** but rather the half only. Why? Because each time you remove a child, the rest closes to eat up the freed index, so your script removes them as following:

```
Initial picture  :  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Remove child at 0:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Remove child at 1:  1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Remove child at 2:  1 3 5 6 7 8 9
Remove child at 3:  1 3 5 7 8 9
```

The correct way to remove **ALL** the children from a given container is either a **backward** loop that removes at the given moment the last child:

```
for (var i = mainContainer.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    mainContainer.removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Or a **while** loop that removes children at depth 0 while there are any:

```
while (mainContainer.numChildren > 0)
{
    mainContainer.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

However, there's a much simpler way to empty a container (available from Flash Player 11 and on):

```
mainContainer.removeChildren();
```

**Garbage Collector**

What for GC, the general idea is that there's no valid references from the application scope (things attached to the **stage** and static class members) to these objects.

If you are sure that nothing on the scope refer them or is subscribed to them, then GC will do its job properly.

Personally I always compose a method called **destroy(...)** that dismantles everything within the given object: unsubscribes all event listeners, renders **Array**s to a length of 0, assigns **null** to every and each **Object**-typed variable, removes children, etc.

I also agree with *Jyreel*, relying on display containers to hold things for you is not a programmer's way to do things, but to use this way, or to devise more complicated data structures, that decision is up to you and your understanding.

Comment: Ah thank you for this answer, I actually didn't know about the destroy() method.  That would be much easier than what I was doing which was similar to the op idea.  I had similar code except I made it work somehow without stepping through the entire earray.  I think I used something like the while loop.  I can't believe I didn't catch the op's for loop which would not get rid of everything because the for loop index goes up while the array is pushing everything back a step.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the answer depends on the listener type. There are two, "strong" and "weak" listeners, the former need to be explicitly removed unless listening at the same object, the latter do not. These differ by setting [`useWeakReference`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()) parameter when calling `addEventListener()` to true for weak and false (default) for strong reference.

An example: If your MC class has this in code:

```
public function Example1() {
    ....
    if (stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
}
private function init(e:Event=null) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
}
```

that listener got handled by the code already, but should you say `stage.addEventListener(...)` in `init()`, these must be removed explicitly before the instance of this class could be garbage collected, provided the listener isn't declared "weak". However, if you say add a listener like this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,someFunction);
```

these listeners do not need to be explicitly removed to have an instance garbage collected, even if they are "strong", because these only represent internal references, which get invalidated alongside the object they are referred in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found on google:
"If an object that is removed is reference-free (no references pointing to it) then yes - the element itself is picked up by the garbage collector as well as any event handlers/listeners associated with it"

Personally I find making a sprite named "gameObjects"  and then addchild(gameObjects) and then making an array and then doing the arrayName.push(object) to be much easier than making a container, but I've never really worked with containers.

If you want the code for removing event listeners it is pretty much the same as adding them just switch add with remove.

Here is a rough idea of the code you would need for using arrays and sprites to do the same thing you are trying to do, but if you find containers easier then just ignore this part:

```
private var gameObjectsArray:Array;
private var gameObjects:Sprite;
public function Start(){
            gameObjects = new Sprite();
            addChild(gameObjects);
            gameObjectsArray = new Array();
            var myObject:object = new object();
            gameObjects.addChild(object);
            gameObjectsArray.push(object);
}
```

if it's not a game then just replace "gameObjects" with whatever name you want and replace "object" with the instance you create, modify and add to the array.

TL:DR - You don't need to remove the event listeners separately if you are removing the objects that they are connected with.  I'm not totally sure, but I think the line that was commented out shouldn't be needed, but I don't know a ton about containers.  Try a bunch of different things and you'll find the answer.  Sometimes using a trace("1") with 1 being replaced with any string, or a variable without the quotes helps a lot.